# How to use calloc to init struct

Tags: c, linux, malloc, calloc

I have struct

```
struct Person
{
    char name[50];
    int citNo;
    float salary;
};
```

Now I do this code:

```
struct Person* p = malloc (sizeof(struct Person));
memset (p,0x00,sizeof(struct Person));
```

now I want to convert that to calloc (clean code) , how can I do that?

```
struct Person* p = calloc(sizeof(struct Person) ,1);
```

Or maybe put `1` it's not correct? what is the right way?

Comment: `struct Person p*` => `struct Person *p` for starters

Comment: well it's `void *calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);` so it's the other way round for arguments. But it probably works anyway

Comment: first arg is the number of elements, the second is the size in bytes of each element

Comment: Have you tried that `calloc` call? What does the compiler tell you?

Comment: I have tried but I ask if this code is right way

Comment: Perhaps all you really need is [a decent `calloc` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I read so I can do `struct Person* p = calloc(sizeof(struct Person) ,1); ` or `struct Person* p = calloc(1, sizeof(struct Person)); ` right?

Comment: The latter only, to be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**calloc() description from man7**

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 void *calloc(size_t nelem, size_t elsize);
```

> The `calloc()` function shall allocate unused space for an array of
>   `nelem` elements each of whose size in bytes is `elsize`.  The space shall
>   be initialized to all `bits 0`. The order and contiguity of storage
>   allocated by successive calls to `calloc()` is unspecified. The pointer
>   returned if the allocation ...

I encourage you to keep reading in the link [man7_calloc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/calloc.3p.html).

now after reading the description above, calling `calloc` seems easy to me:
in your case we allocating array of one `struct person`

```
struct Person* p = NULL;
struct Person* p = calloc(1, sizeof(struct Person));
```

you must check the return value of `calloc`(if calloc succedd to allocate, like malloc):

```
if(p == NULL){
  puts("calloc failed");
  ...
  ...
}
```

Comment: Why did you write `struct Person* p = NULL;` before `calloc`? if calloc will failed it will return NULL

Comment: generaly and a good habbit in C, If you are not sure about which variable's address to assign to a pointer variable while declaration, it is recommended to assign a NULL value to your pointer variable. In this case we immediatley assigned the return value of `calloc()` to this pointer, so in this case it is less important, but as a general rule, its a good practice to get use to it!

Comment: @MicrosoctCprog - if my answer helped you please vote up and accept it by marking the grey V nearby/ the new thanks emoji! thank you.